# Jquery datepicker not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker

I have strange issue on datepicker that I cant choose date from FIREFOX rather it accepts date (typed manually) as input to process.

I am using Jquery date picker USING jquery version v1.11.2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var time_value = '01.12.2000';
    var values = time_value.split(".");
    var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1], values[0]);

    $("#todate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-150:c",
        minDate: parsed_date,
        maxDate: "+0d"
    });

    var todate = '<?=str_replace('-', '/',$totimestamp);?>'

    if (todate != 'NULL') {
        $("#todate").datepicker("setDate", todate);
    }

    $("#fromdate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-150:c",
        minDate: parsed_date,
        maxDate: "+0d"
    });

    var fromdate = '<?= str_replace('-', '/',$fromtimestamp);?>';

    if (fromdate != 'NULL') {
        $("#fromdate").datepicker("setDate", fromdate);
    }
});
```

This works fine with chrome and other browsers ( I could choose from date selector) but in firefox its not working.

I tried with sample independently it works fine.

Comment: any errors in your console

Comment: checked, no console error.

Comment: This is invalid string `'<?=str_replace('-', '/',$totimestamp);?>'`.
Use double quotes.

Comment: do you at least get the calendar popup?

Comment: @imkost - that's php - so, probably not an issue (that would definitely sow an error on the console)

Comment: yes, it open slide calendar popup fine. ( but I could not select)

Comment: @JaromandaX, what do you mean by `that's php`? This code is a JS code. JS will return `NaN` for the given expression (string - string / string). But yeh, seems like OP does not have an issue when he runs his code.

Comment: checked even with double quotes as suggested by imkost

Comment: @imkost - `I'm not familiar with php` - that's where you should've stopped ... `but this code looks very like js code` yes, it is JS, however it is preprocessed by php and the OP hasn't posted the POST processed code

Comment: @Mohan - is this script in a html page preprocessed by php?

Comment: @jaromanda X : this script is in php page under <script></script> tag.

Comment: @JaromandaX, preprocessing. I've got it now. Thanks

Comment: used double quotes but not working . yes i viewed calendar but couldnot choose date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Not sure whether your code even worked in any other browsers also.I see the syntax error `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`
 you need to close document ready.try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var time_value = '01.12.2000';
    var values = time_value.split(".");
    var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1], values[0]);
    $( "#todate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange:"-150:c",minDate:parsed_date,maxDate: "+0d"});
    var todate="<?=str_replace('-', '/',$totimestamp);?>";
    if (todate != 'NULL') {
        $("#todate").datepicker("setDate",todate);
    }

    $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange:"-150:c",minDate:parsed_date,maxDate: "+0d"});
    var fromdate="<?= str_replace('-', '/',$fromtimestamp);?>";
    if (fromdate!= 'NULL') {
        $("#fromdate").datepicker("setDate",fromdate);
    }
});
```

```html
<link  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fromdate"/> <input type="text" id="todate"/>
```

```
Or Try setting z-index of input to something like 10000 and see
```

Comment: Actually I included "}".
I missed only while post here.

Comment: @Mohan are you getting the calender view.

Comment: yeah, getting calendar view. issue is not able to select on the calendar.

Comment: @Mohan since i'm not able to replicate your issue ,i'm not sure whether it will help or not but try setting `z-index` of input to something like `10000` and see.

Comment: Thank you Suchit. 
yours input was out of box thinking. worked well. 
removed the z-index:-1 and border set in the included header file. :-)

Comment: @Mohan then you can mark it as answer so it will help later users of SO.

Answer (score 1):

This code works on IE, firefox and explorer

```
<html>  
<body>
    <div>
        FromDate: <input type="text" id="fromdate" class="datepicker"/>
        ToDate: <input type="text" id="todate" class="datepicker"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            var time_value = '01.12.2000';
            var values = time_value.split(".");
            var parsed_date = new Date(values[2], values[1], values[0]);
            $("#todate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',changeMonth: true,changeYear: true,yearRange:"-150:c",minDate:parsed_date,maxDate: "+0d"});
             var todate="<?=str_replace('-', '/','19-11-2015');?>"
            if (todate != 'NULL') {
                $("#todate").datepicker("setDate",todate);
            }

            $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',changeMonth: true,     changeYear: true,yearRange:"-150:c",minDate:parsed_date,maxDate: "+0d"});
            var fromdate="<?= str_replace('-', '/','21-11-2015');?>"
            if (fromdate!= 'NULL') {
                 $("#fromdate").datepicker("setDate",fromdate);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here it is the link to jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tz3qLaa8/

Please note that the code

```
 var todate = '<?=str_replace('-', '/',$totimestamp);?>'
```

is wrong. You need to use double quote on openinig and closing the string because you use the single quote inside the string